# running example server, access web page status failed

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run the docker example in the tutorial here https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/usingdocker/

I used the same command as they do :

```
run -d -P training/webapp python app.py
```

then it says that the container is running :

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
dfd286f172a0        training/webapp     "python app.py"     7 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:32769->5000/tcp   dreamy_bhabha
```

When trying to access it via http://localhost:32769 the site can't be reached. The status code is : status failed.

I thought it could be my firewall so I tried with my firewall and antivirus desactivated. Still no luck. I don't know why it's not working, any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the note they put under the tutorial (and it's admittedly badly placed).

> Note: If you have been using a virtual machine on OS X, Windows or
>   Linux, you’ll need to get the IP of the virtual host instead of using
>   localhost. You can do this by running the docker-machine ip
>   your_vm_name from your command line or terminal application

"If you have been using a virtual machine on **OS X, Windows or Linux**"... Chances are people are, seems like something they shouldn't put in the foot note. /rant